# Organize and manage items on iPod Touch/iPhone

Tags: icons, iphone, ipod, ipod-touch

I am a new user of the iPod Touch. It seems that the icons on the phone are just in a random order and spread across multiple screens. Is there a way to manage these like on my Blackberry? I would like to move them to different screens based on my preferences, but cannot seem to find a way. Nor can I really find a way to remove them other than by un-syncing them in iTunes. What am I doing wrong/missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the iPhone Touch User Guide available [here](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPod_touch_3.0_User_Guide.pdf)

```
1. Touch and hold any Home Screen icon until the icons begin to wiggle
2. Arrange the icons by dragging them
3. Press the home button to save the configuration
```

Look under the Customizing the Home Screen section.

To remove an application:

```
1. Touch and hold any Home Screen icon until the icons begin to wiggle
2. Tap X on the corner of the Application you want to delete
3. Tap Delete and then home to Save the Home Screen
```

This can be found in the Deleting Applications section. Also ensure that you remove it in iTunes otherwise it will re-appear the next time you sync.

Comment: Thanks, I must have tried everything except that. Thanks!

Comment: You can set iTunes to only sync selected applications. That way when you delete an app from the iPhone it will still remain in iTunes, but will not reappear when you sync your iPhone again.

Answer (score 2):

Press and hold your finger on any icon, until it starts to jiggle.

[image: Jiggling apps]

Then you can get rid of any item by tapping the “X” or re-arrange them by dragging them around. You can drag them to other pages by dragging them to the edge of the screen.

When you're finished moving items around, hit the Home button to exit "jiggling mode".

Answer (score 2):

With iTunes 9, you can additionally manage the order of the apps in iTunes and then synch your iPod Touch.

Comment: Yeah, I was excited when they added that feature.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move a bunch of apps between pages, you might want to temporarily empty your Bottom Row onto the last page, then use that row as a bucket for apps you're moving.

This is much faster & easier than trying to drag each individual app across several screens without displacing any of the icons on the way.